# Jumping from one JFrame to the next not working using ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to get my Frame when 'Start' button is clicked to go the my class 'Frame', however when I do that the Frame simply just closes instead of doing anything. I am doing this in Java Swing for a school project, so Swing is part of the requirements. If anyone could tell me why this is happening, I would really appreciate it! (I took out the imports for this but I imported all the necessary things) Here's my code:

```
    package snake;

public class Start extends JFrame  implements ActionListener {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Start frame = new Start();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Start() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 800, 500);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

    JLabel lblSnake = new JLabel("Snake");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblSnake = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblSnake.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_lblSnake.gridx = 7;
    gbc_lblSnake.gridy = 0;
    contentPane.add(lblSnake, gbc_lblSnake);

    JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnStart = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnStart.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_btnStart.gridx = 7;
    gbc_btnStart.gridy = 3;
    contentPane.add(btnStart, gbc_btnStart);

    // action listener for start btn
    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        // once this is clicked on, it should call the GUI
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Frame();
            // closes the old form after start is clicked
            dispose();

        }
    });

    JButton btnBack = new JButton("Back");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnBack = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnBack.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_btnBack.gridx = 7;
    gbc_btnBack.gridy = 5;
    contentPane.add(btnBack, gbc_btnBack);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("\t\t\t        SNAKE INSTRUCTIONS:\t\t\t\n\n\n1) Use the right, left, up, and down arrow keys to move the snake right, left, up, and down respectively.\n\n2) Each apple collected by the snake is a point\n\n3) If the snake collides with the wall or itself the game is over and you lose!\n\nWe hope you enjoy playing this old-school snake throwback!");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textArea = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_textArea.gridx = 7;
    gbc_textArea.gridy = 7;
    contentPane.add(textArea, gbc_textArea);



}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


 }
```

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). (The `Frame` class seems to be missing, for starters. BTW - given it is also the name of the `java.awt.Frame`, I'd recommend naming it more usefully & explicitly - something like `GameFrame` or whatever.)

Comment: Those points should be addressed, OTOH, I have spotted the immediate problem. Guess what happens when a frame on which `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` is set does, when it is disposed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, you are trying to open a new one own Frame. Look at thit part:

```
@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Frame();
            // closes the old form after start is clicked
            dispose();

        }
```

You are creating a Frame without a variable. And after creating a Frame object you should to make it visible, like this:

```
@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Frame frame1 = new Frame();
            frame1.setVisible(true);
            // closes the old form after start is clicked
            dispose();

        }
```

Because your Frame appears invisible by default.